# Is there an R function for renaming the variables of a column?

Tags: r

I want to replace values in a column using R code.  Data frame is DT. The column name is Data.  It has values 1 and 2 repeatedly. I want a code to replace all 1 with Asia and 2 with India.

Comment: `DT$Data  = ifelse(DT$Data == 1, "Asia", "India")`

Comment: Or convert them to factors: `DT$Data <- factor(DT$Data, labels =c("Asia", "India"))`

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly.